# What is the difference of term "Chef Infra Client" and "Chef Client"

Tags: chef-infra

Just a quick question as the title.
The term "Chef Infra Client" seems suddenly popped up recently without any exclamation of whether it is just a name changed from "Chef Client".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of **Chef Client** was changed to **Chef Infra Client** with version **15.0.293**. There seems to be no difference in terms of the functionality.

Quoting from the [release notes](https://docs.chef.io/release_notes_client/#whats-new-in-150293):

> ### Chef Client is now Chef Infra Client
>
> Chef Client has a new name, but don’t worry, it’s the same Chef Client you’ve grown used to.